# Conjunciones "tan pronto como" y "en cuanto"

Tags: conjunciones

¿Me podéis aclarar una duda por favor? Se trata de las conjunciones *tan pronto como* y *en cuanto*. 
En algunos libros leo que son conjunciones que expresan posterioridad inmediata y en otros que expresan anterioridad inmediata.

Pues ¿qué tipo de relación establecen? ¿de anterioridad o posterioridad?

Answer (score 3):

Depende del contexto. Estas expresiones se utilizan en la conversación informal para hablar del futuro y del pasado.

Creo que la regla mas simple es fijarse como esta conjugado el verbo. Los he marcado en **negrita** para resaltar la diferencia.

**Ejemplos:**

- Tan pronto como

Posterioridad: **Hazlo** *tan pronto como* sea posible.

Anterioridad: *Tan pronto como* **acabó** de hacerlo, se marcho a su casa.

- En cuando

Posterioridad: *En cuanto* **acabe**, le enviaré una respuesta.

Anterioridad: *En cuanto* se **marchó** su jefe, preparo sus cosas para irse.

Comment: Tanto en «Tan pronto como acabó de hacerlo, se marcho a su casa» como en «Hazlo tan pronto como sea posible», la locución conjuntiva «tan pronto como» denota posterioridad (sin importar que la oración esté haciendo referencia a un evento que pasó o a uno que va a pasar).